# Adding ASP or Dynamic Content into the FCK textbox

Tags: dotnetnuke, fckeditor

I'd like to add some dynamic content into the FCK text box when I'm adding links, for example when I add a link or link some text I want to be able to put some ASP delimeters into the textbox and a variable name. Something like this `<%= myLinkVariable %>`.

I've tried looking at the textbox content in the source view and adding a simple `<% Response.Write("Hello World")%>` but like the link text the asp delimeters have been converted to unicode/html like this `&lt;% Response.Write("hello world")%&gt;"`

Do I need to comment / uncommment the

```
FCKConfig.ProtectedSource.Add( /<%[\s\S]*?%>/g ) ;  // ASP style server side code <%...%>
```

or any of the other custom items in the custom.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FCK Editor only deals with HTML content.  You won't be able to use it to access server variables, unless you have a custom module designed to parse and evaluate the content.